# how to omit "-" if it exists in a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have  a database table that  has prefix and phone number fields they are varchar2 so user can enter a phone number as +1999 999-9999 now i need to select the numerical values only and leave out the - in a select statement. So the + sign is selected but the - sign is not selected how can I do this? I am reading up on substr but this is getting confusing

Comment: You want to show + sign but not - sign in the results?

Comment: so you want to remove the '-" characters. But do you want to replace each with a space? Do you want to remove spaces too?

Comment: I have tried this SELECT coalesce(trim(t6.prefix) || '' || replace(trim(t6.phonenumber),'-','')) FROM some_table t6 I am getting not enough argument in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select replace(phonenumber,'-','') from yourtable
```

This will remove the - sign from your select results, while keeping + intact. If you want to remove the + sign as well, just nest the `replace` function calls.

Comment: I tired this but it says not enough arguments for the function  this is my code 
SELECT coalesce(trim(t6.prefix) || '' || replace(trim(t6.phonenumber),'-','')) FROM some_table t6

Comment: That's because you are only passing one single argument to the function when it expects at least 2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF51280. What do you want this function to return if the expression inside `COALESCE` is null? That should be the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks I got it  I was just getting confused on the order how it should closed it worked for me thanks